# How to stop WordPress from automatically doing a redirect?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a site running on WordPress, and it will automatically redirects URLs it thinks are written incorrectly.

For example, if I go to a URL that doesn't exist. Like this one:

```
www.example.com/blah-blah/my-page-slug/
```

will redirect me to...

```
www.example.com/my-page-slug/
```

How can I stop this redirection? I want to generate a 404 error if the wrong URL is typed in, not redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place this in your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
remove_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```